# MacVim cannot find gems when launched from the command line

Tags: ruby, rubygems, macvim

I have MacVim installed with Janus and a few extra lines in both .vimrc.local and .gvimrc.local.

When I launch mvim from the terminal (iterm2 or terminal) and try !rails -v I get
Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)

Launching MacVim from the dock and doing !rails -v works fine and returns Rails 3.0.7.

I get the same behaviour with all gems.

I realise I'll likely have to provide more information to solve this but tbh I have no idea whether it is macvim, rvm, bash, or something else causing the issue.

TIA

Comment: rvm not loaded could be the cause, give a look at this: http://beginrescueend.com/integration/vim/

Comment: Some time ago I followed this fix https://github.com/robgleeson/hammer.vim/issues/8 to get hammer.vim working.
The fix involved adding
mvim() .
{
  (unset GEM_PATH GEM_HOME; command mvim "$@")
}
to .bashrc which obviously was going to cause an issue when I returned to rails coding.
I have put this as a comment rather than an answer as I don't feel I should reward my own stupidity. Thanks to those that took the time to comment / answer and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

I also use MacVim (I'm running it from iTerm (screen)), and !rails -v works.

Did you set rvm installed ruby interpreter to be default ruby executable on system? Try running

```
which ruby
```

from terminal, and also you could try to run !which ruby from MacVim. You should get something like:

```
/Users/your_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
```

If not, try setting one of your rvm installed rubies as default (As explained on http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/default/).